use different major-mode font-lock-keywords when inside {{ }}
I'm trying to create a major-mode in emacs to view HTTP requests which has its own syntax highlighting, now I want to syntax-highlight text inside {{ }} with python font-lock-keywords.
for example here is a what I would like to have:
GET /test HTTP/1.1
custom-header: {{"this is a python generated code".upper()}}


I want to highlight every aspect of the request using my custom font-lock-keywords, which I can do easily, but I want the text inside the {{ }} to be highlighted with python font-lock, which I cannot figure out how to do.
